# Qual a diferença entre Sessions Beans e Message DriveBeans?

Tags: ejb, java

Há dois componentes responsáveis pela lógica de negócio na arquitetura EJB, os
Session Beans e Message DriveBeans. Gostaria de saber qual a diferença de ambos e algum exemplo de seu uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enquanto que os MDB são stateless os SB podem ser stateless ou statfull além de os MDB terem um período de vida curta e acederem ás mensagens de forma assíncrona. Além disso não podes aceder ao MDB através de uma interface.